# How can I write a Ruby method that allows me create a new row in a destination table while editing an attribute in the source table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, nomethoderror

```
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-darwin14]
Rails 4.2.5.2
```

So I've been struggling with this for a couple of days and not sure where to focus. My scenario: My user clicks a button on a source request view at REQUEST/index that creates a new row in my PERFORMANCE destination table and assigns attributes from the source. At the same time I need to flip a boolean attribute in the source table (REQUEST).

My code is below:

REQUEST VIEW

```
<%= new_performance_path( :attribute_id1 => (source.attribute_id1), :attribute_id2 => (source.attribute_id2), :attribute_id3 => (source.attribute_id3)), class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

PERFORMANCE CONTROLLER/NEW

```
def new
    @performance = Performance.new(:attribute_id1 => params[:attribute_id1], :attribute_id2 => params[:attribute_id2], :attribute_id3 => params[:attribute_id3] )
    @performance.completed = false
    @performance.save
    if @request.present?
      @request.available = false  #  Need to assign 'false' to this boolean attribute
      @request.save  #  Then save it.
    end
    redirect_to :performances
end
```

While the code creates the new row in my PERFORMANCE table I can't figure out the method syntax to effectively flip the REQUEST table attribute to "false". This code with the if statement processes without throwing an erorr. I've originally tried this in the PERFORMANCE CONTROLLER/NEW, without the if statement, which results in an internal server error:

```
  def new
    ...
    @request.available = false
    @request.save
    ...
  end
```

RAILS CONSOLE

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 10.1ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `available=' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/performances_controller.rb:26:in `new'
```

So I think this means I can't call available on request in my performances model. Based on that I tried to add a method to my PERFORMANCE model...

PERFORMANCE.RB

```
  def available
    Request.where( :available == true )
  end
```

...but the error persists. My thinking is that I need to grab all rows in the REQUEST table where the boolean value 'available' is equal to true.

Note that these two tables are not directly related to each other. REQUESTS is a join table in my domain model. The app is a music request app, so a USER has_many :REQUESTS, and :PERFORMANCES and I'm using existing rows in the REQUEST table to build new rows in the PERFORMANCE table, but need to edit the row in the request table when a new row is created in performance.

Thanks guys. Still learning being new to Rails and I struggle with referential relationships especially. Thanks for taking a look and helping me out.

Comment: is @request initialized in controller? Can't see it in new action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shishir - After more research on Stack I ended up making my model fatter with a new method & thinning out the controller. This appears to have worked.

PERFORMANCE CONTROLLER/NEW

```
 def new
    ...
    @performance.save
    # After @performance is saved we point to new method in performance.rb
    @performance.remove_request
    # it then comes back for the redirect
    redirect_to :performances, notice: "..."
  end
```

performance.rb

```
  def remove_request
    @request = Request.find_by(:available => true)
    if @request.available == true
      @request.available = false
    end
    @request.save
  end
```

This effectively sets the request to 'false' which displays as expected in my request view. Thanks for your help buddy and forcing me to think about this differently. Cheers, my friend.

Comment: So my code appears to function correctly but is flipping the values sequentially instead of grabbing the correct object. For example, if I have requests ID #101 through #104 and need to select #103 first, it will instead flip #101 then #102,  ad so on. I feel like this should be an easy fix. Any clues?

Comment: Adding :user_id => self.user_id to the look up effectively initializes @request and selects the correct row. Good to go.

Answer (score 0):

@request object is nil in your controller action new. Hence the error

```
undefined method `available=' for nil:NilClass
```

Initialize @request should fix the above error.

EDIT 1:
** wrote pseudo code, please read the comments have explaination.

```
def new
  # Load the user objects
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])

  # User has many performances, use build method to associated 
  # user and newly build performance.
  @user.performance.build({
    :attribute_id1 => params[:attribute_id1], 
    :attribute_id2 => params[:attribute_id2], 
    :attribute_id3 => params[:attribute_id3],
    :completed     => false;
  })

  # User has one request (This is an assumption). 
  # if its is  has many you can use the above mentioned method to 
  # create new request method same as performance.
  if @performance.save
      @user.request.available = false  #  Need to assign 'false' to this boolean attribute
      @user.request.save  #  Then save it.
    end
  end
  redirect_to :performances
end
```

Comment: Tried that. (@request = Request.find_by(:user_id => params[:user_id]) ) This code eliminates the error message but doesn't solve the functionality issue. The page is redirected but the boolean value in requests remains unchanged. Any idea why this code isn't processing?

Comment: Do a save! on @request instead of save and to see if there are some  validation error.

Comment: Same. With save! on (@request), it's throwing no errors. SQL shows everything in the action being processed except for the (@request) assignment and save.  After the performance transaction is committed it selects the (@request) but I don't see the boolean assignment or save. Still no errors!  Any thoughts on where I should look next?

Comment: I have edited the answer. But the problem with your code seems that performance is not getting associated to user and same for request. This is an assumption based on the description of the question. let me know how it goes. Since i have not tested the code, you might have to tweak it a bit to get it running.

Comment: eh...much appreciated but still a "no go" @Shishir. When I look at the console I can see that user is associated to both the new performance and the source request so I'm not sure where to go from here. If I find a solution I will update this thread. I know I'm close.